# Swift 2 - add decimal 0 to CGFloat

Tags: swift2, decimalformat, cgfloat

I am trying to convert a string into `CGFloat` number.
The code I have cuts out the last digit if equal to `0`.

How can I prevent to cut out the zeros?

```
let str = "17.30"

let flt = CGFloat((str as NSString).doubleValue) + 2.0

print(flt) // 19.3 -- should be 19.30
```

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the precision (number of decimals) originally used in the string, or do you always want to format the result with 2 decimals?

Comment: I ma trying to format always the result with 2 decimals

Comment: @SNos If you want to convert a number to a string, use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGFloat` can't do that, convert the float back to `String`

```
print(String(format: "%.2f", flt)) // 19.30
```

Answer (score 2):

**For swift 4**

Try using `NumberFormatter` in `.decimal` format:

let text = "123456.789"

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let value = formatter.string(from: text! as NSNumber)!

print(value)

Output: 123,456.78
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CGFloat` is just a number (so `17.3` and `17.30` is the same value for it); what you're really concerned is how to set the `String` representation of your `CGFloat` number.

As an alternative to @vadian:s solution, you can make use of an `NSNumberFormatter` as follows

```
/* Your CGFloat example */
let str = "17.30"
let flt = CGFloat((str as NSString).doubleValue) + 2.0

/* Use NSNumberFormatter to display your CGFloat 
   with exactly 2 fraction digits.  */
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(flt)!)
    /* 19.30 */
```

Comment: `?? ""` makes little sense in this case, you want to raise an exception when conversion fails (because it should never happen), not silently swallow it. I would use `!`.

Comment: @Sulthan You're right; stems from my (here: possibly bad) habit out of avoiding using `!` when answering SO questions out of fear of misguidedly teaching someone to use `!` for unwrapping in less appropriate situations. With these two comments, this will hopefully not be the case here, thanks for pointing this out!